# Why doesn't Heroku detect my Procfile?

Tags: heroku, flask, python-3.6

Heroku does not see my Procfile and begins installing the wrong version of py.

I'm trying to upload an extremely basic flask app using Heroku. As per other suggestions on SO, I've created my Procfile, runtime.txt, and requirements.txt using the command line, rather than through an editor. I've also ensured that they are located in the base git directory. When I enter

```
$ git push heroku master
```

I get the following:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Warning: Your application is missing a Procfile. This file tells Heroku how to run your application.
remote:  !     Learn more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
remote: -----> Installing python-2.7.13
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Invalid requirement: 'Python 3.6.1'
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 82, in __init__
remote:            req = Requirement(req)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-package/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 96, in __init__
remote:            requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
remote:        InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "u'3.6.1'"
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to salty-springs-82445.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/salty-springs-82445.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/salty-springs 82445.git'
```

Contents of Procfile:

```
web: python run.py
```

Here is the project structure:

```
▾ Random_world/                                                          
  ▸ __pycache__/                                                         
  ▾ app/                                                                 
    ▸ __pycache__/                                                     
    ▸ static/                                                            
    ▸ templates/                                                         
      __init__.py                                                        
      main.py*                                                           
      test.txt                                                           
  ▸ venv/                                                                
    config.py                                                            
    d.py*                                                                
    os                                                                   
    Procfile                                                             
    randomizer.py                                                        
    randomizer.pyc                                                       
    README.md                                                            
    requirements.txt                                                     
    run.py*                                                              
    runtime.txt                                                          
    test.txt                                                             
    word_blocks.py                                                   
    word_blocks.pyc
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. The Procfile was in my .gitignore, stupidly added by me.

Sidenote: the app wouldn't deploy at all because I was pushing from the wrong branch.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you forgot to add and commit your Procfile to git.